# Windows 10 Bluetooth Low Energy GATT Pairing Is Not working c#

Tags: c#-4.0, windows-10-universal, bluetooth-lowenergy, windows-10-iot-core

This is code for BLE pairing. it's working on Bluetooth refreshing from windows 10 setting at every time.

```
DevicePairingKinds ceremoniesSelected = DevicePairingKinds.ConfirmOnly | DevicePairingKinds.DisplayPin | DevicePairingKinds.ProvidePin | DevicePairingKinds.ConfirmPinMatch;
DevicePairingProtectionLevel protectionLevel = DevicePairingProtectionLevel.Default;
DeviceInformationCustomPairing customPairing = deviceInfoDisp.DeviceInformation.Pairing.Custom;

customPairing.PairingRequested += PairingRequestedHandler;
DevicePairingResult result = await customPairing.PairAsync(ceremoniesSelected, protectionLevel);
```

customPairing.PairingRequested -= PairingRequestedHandler;

Comment: fix your code this won't compile what is `protection level EncryptionAndAuthentication` at the end of line 3

Comment: Thanks johnny, i have edited the code but problem is same i'm getting same problem on pairing with any BLE devices.

Comment: do you have an error log or more information on whats happening?

Comment: Thank you Johnny, I'm not getting any Error and log but always getting the result.Status=Pairing Failed; and apart  from this i have downloaded the sample project from https://github.com/ms-iot/samples/archive/develop.zip and this sample project is also giving same type of result. and i'm using Visual Studio-2015 updated-2(Professional) and Windows 10 pro OS. Can you please suggest me the any other API and other Think so that i can do stable Pairing with any BLE devices

Comment: When the pairing fails, the IOT sample prints out `UserOut.Text = "Pairing Failed " + result.Status.ToString();` What is the `result.Status.ToString()` resolving as?